# Images uploaded from mobile rotated in Chrome and Firefox on Desktop

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I have this weird problem that if I upload an image from mobile to my website, the image will appear rotated on Chrome and Firefox **desktop**
It will appear in the right directions on the **mobile browsers** (Chrome mobile and Safari Mobile)

Seems like there was a CSS field (now deprecated) image-orientation: from-image. But seems not to work anymore

Other people suggest removing the EXIF info from the file, but that did not work either.

Did someone encounter the same problem?

Comment: Do you have a demo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in the EXIF data that iOS embed in the media.
If you process the media with Sharp, it will automatically process it and **scrape** it off.
Hope it helps anyone coming across this answer!